# How to create a query with two joins to the same lookup table

Tags: mysql

I am hoping someone can point me in the correct direction, I am just an amateur playing with a hobby.

I have 2 tables, first table 'tbl_wheel_diameter' has just 'wheel_diameter' and 'id'

Second table 'tbl_tyres' has 'wheel_diameter_front','wheel_diameter_rear' and 'vehicleId'

I need to write a query that selects the front and rear diameter together.
This is something I tried.

```
SELECT  tbl_wheel_diameter.wheel_diameter_front,tbl_wheel_diameter.wheel_diameter_rear
FROM tbl_tyres
INNER JOIN tbl_wheel_diameter
     ON tbl_wheel_diameter.id = tbl_tyres.wheel_diameter
WHERE tbl_tyres.vehicleId = 2
```

I have read that I should use left joins but I seem to get confused with how to write them?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Mono - I suggest you create your table here: http://sqlfiddle.com/ put the link into your question. This allows us to answer your question a lot quicker! :)

Comment: *query that selects the front and rear diameter together.* they are extracted independently (selected value for first not influenced on second). So use 2 independent table copies - one is used to obtain first value, and 2nd...

Comment: And what's wrong with your query?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN is something you would prefer to avoid if you can. It does not seem required as you exposed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an alias for the table so you can include the same table twice. Here is an example using an alias of t1 and t2.

```
SELECT  t1.wheel_diameter,t2.wheel_diameter
FROM tbl_tyres
INNER JOIN tbl_wheel_diameter t1
     ON t1.id = tbl_tyres.wheel_diameter_front
INNER JOIN tbl_wheel_diameter t2
     ON t2.id = tbl_tyres.wheel_diameter_rear
WHERE tbl_tyres.vehicleId = 1
```